# Type Error: argument of type 'Word2Vec' is not iterable

Tags: types, arguments, word2vec, iterable

```
 doc2vecs = Doc2VecTrainer(Xs, embd_size, w, min_word_count, worker_threads)

  File "C:\Users\PC 5\Desktop\embedding.py", line 63, in Doc2VecTrainer
    if Samples[i][j] in word2vec_model:

TypeError: argument of type 'Word2Vec' is not iterable
```

here is code

```
def Doc2VecTrainer(Samples, embd_size, win_size, min_word_count, n_workers):
    from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec as w2v

    word2vec_model = w2v(Samples, vector_size =embd_size, window=win_size, min_count=min_word_count, workers=n_workers)
    #model.save("word2vec.model")
    #model = Word2Vec.load("word2vec.model")
    #word2vec_model['robust']

    """
        step three:
        average top-n keywords vectors and compute similarities
    """
    doc2vecs = []
    print(word2vec_model)
    for i in range(0, len(Samples)):
        vec = [0 for k in range(embd_size)]
        for j in range(0, len(Samples[i])):
            print(type(word2vec_model))
            **if Samples[i][j] in word2vec_model:
                vec += word2vec_model[Samples[i][j]]**
        doc2vecs.append(vec)
    return doc2vecs
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should include in your question the **full, multiline error you've received, with all 'traceback' showing involved files/lines-of-code**. That, more than anything else, can help narrow down where things are going wrong in your code – better than the sort of `**` extra non-functional characters you've added to highlight an involved line.

However, here the problem is clear even without that: your `word2vec_model` variable has inside it a Gensim `Word2Vec` model object. Exactly as the error says, that object is not iterable. (You can't just drop it into Python constructs, like your `in` test on the problem line `if Samples[i][j] in word2vec_model:`, that attempt to work by looking through each item of an iterable sequence to work.

The simple direct fix is for you to instead direct your `in` test, and your later vector-lookup, at the `word2vec_model.wv` subcomponent instead. It is an instance of a Gensim `KeyedVectors` model object, and contains all the word-vectors of the model. It can answer an `in`.

However, there are a number of other performance/style/correctness issues with your code:

- Importing a Python class type  `Word2Vec` as the (lower-case) `w2v` breaks Python style conventions, making your code harder for others to understand
- Calling this function a (capitalized) `Doc2VecTrainer` violates the convetion that capitals are usually reserved for classes/types. And, there is another algorithm in Gensim called `Doc2Vec`, which is *not* an average-of-word-vectors. So the name here is misleading.
- Calling your data object (capitalized) `Samples` is also non-standard.
- Python loops generally iterate over each actual item in the sequence, rather than using `i`, `j`, etc numeric-index accessing (unless those indexes are necessary). So a more-Pythonic set of loops would be instead:

```
    for sample in samples:
        for word in sample:
            if word in word2vec_model.wv:
                vec += word2vec_model.wv[word]
```

- Your comment implies you are averaging the vectors - but so far, your code just adds them. Don't forget to take the average, if that's the intent.

Good luck!